# Is there a way to resolve Rails deleted migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, migration, rails-migrations

I happened to have deleted migrations and I don't want to revert these removed migrations.

This is what `rake db:migrate:status` produces:

```
 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
------------------------------------------------------

   up     0               ********** NO FILE *********
   up     20150209023430  Create users 
   up     20150320184628  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150322004817  Add roles to users
   up     20150403190042  ********** NO FILE **********
```

`rake db:migrate` and `rake db:rollback` commands won't work because of the missing files.

I have no intentions to lose my data, so I don't want to use `rake db:drop` or `rake db:reset`.

What can I do to be able to perform **migrate** and **rollback** and how to get rid of the missing files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can find the migration's timestamp - the number part of the filename, then you can do:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20100905201547
```

You can find the timestamp using `rake db:migrate:status`

**Edit** - when the migration file has been irrecoverably deleted

You can get around this by creating an empty migration file, migrating, then rolling back twice. Then, make sure you delete the empty migration file before migrating again.

```
$ bundle exec rails g migration fix_rollback_error
$ bundle exec rails db:migrate
$ bundle exec rails db:rollback STEP=2
$ rm db/migrate/20200217040302_fix_rollback_error.rb
$ bundle exec rails db:migrate
```

Answer (score 16):

Alexander, you can get rid of those non-existing migrations.
when you do `rake db:migrate:status` it will show as in the question.

so you can manually delete those versions from `schema_migrations` table using a pure sql query.

`delete from schema_migrations where version = <version_number>`
by executing above query, it will be resolved.

Comment: or `ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration.where().delete_all`

Comment: @AlexanderShmatko Just to clarify, an array of versions can go in that `where` clause. Like so: ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration.where(version: [20170506145701,20170506145702,20170506145703]).delete_all

Comment: @mkrorfolk I tried using this to remove a migration but i'm getting error: `syntax error near unexpected token `version=20180412191332` full command used:`ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration.where(version=20180412191332).delete_all` can you help please?

Comment: yes that's a syntax error. the `version` should be in a key format like `version: '20180412191332'`

Answer (score 2):

I'd already deleted a migration which I wanted to rollback.

So I:

1. recreated an identical migration,
2. named the migration file after the timestamp rails wanted,
3. ran `rake db:rollback STEP=1`

and it worked.